# Task use internal Theadpool or taskscheduler then how new threads shows in task manager

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Task code creates 14 thread in process -

[image]

```
  Task.Run(()=>abc());
     Task.Run(() => abc());
     Task.Run(() => abc());
     Task.Run(() => abc());
     Task.Run(() => abc());
     Console.Read();
```

---

Thread code creates 10 thread in process
[image]

Thread t = new Thread(abc);
t.Start();
Thread t1 = new Thread(abc);
t1.Start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(abc);
t2.Start();
Thread t3 = new Thread(abc);
t3.Start();
Thread t4 = new Thread(abc);
t4.Start();

Comment: How are you proving this for your self? Also Tasks aren't wrappers for threads, though the Task scheduler may liberate a thread pool thread if it deems necessary and/or feels like it

Comment: Tasks don't create any thread directly, they use thread available in thread pool.

Comment: `Task.Run()` is normally for CPU-bound operations so yes you would expect a thread to be used. However, not all `Task`s require threads such as I/O-bound IOCP code operations where you might find no thread at all.  For these types of operations you wouldn't use `Task.Run`.  https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run(...)` schedules actions/tasks to run on the threadpool:

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work. A cancellation token allows the work to be cancelled if it has not yet started.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_

Also see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netcore-3.1